# Technical and syntax doubts about joins

Tags: oracle, join

i'm having a technical and syntax problem with JOINS in ORACLE.

If i have 7 tables, listed below:

```
 FROM
      QT_QTS.PLA_ORDEM_PRODUCAO pla,
      qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust,
      qt_qts.res_tubo_revenimento1 res_rev1,
      qt_qts.res_tubo_revenimento2 res_rev2,
    limsprod.SAMPLE sp, 
    limsprod.test t,
    limsprod.result r
```

I need to get ALL the data in the *"limsprod.result r"* table linked with similar corresponding data inside the ***qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust***, ***qt_qts.res_tubo_revenimento1 res_rev1*** and           ***qt_qts.res_tubo_revenimento2 res_rev2*** tables.

How can I do this join using Oracle Database? I tried a left join, but it did not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the left join version you tried.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. (Maybe you are confusing left joing with right join? x left join y on c = y right join x on c.) PS [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to answer that question. We have nothing but list of some tables. I'm not sure I'd even want to do that instead of you.

However, here's a suggestion: start with one table:

```
select * from limsprod.result r;
```

It'll return all rows. Then join it to another table:

```
select *
from limsprod.result r join qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust on aust.id = r.id
```

and see what happens - did you get all rows you want? If not, should you add another JOIN condition? Perhaps an outer join? Don't move on to the third table until you sort that out. Once you're satisfied with the result, add another table:

```
select *
from limsprod.result r join qt_qts.res_tubo_austenitizacao aust on aust.id = r.id
                       join qt_qts.res_tubo_revenimento1 res_rev1 on res_rev1.idrr = aust.idrr
```

Repeat what's being said previously.